# Should my new refrigerator have this corrosion on the lines?

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, corrosion

I just unpacked a new Liebherr fridge. These joints of different metals look worrying, as if they have corrosion.

What is this? Is it normal for a brand new premium-line fridge? Can it cause problems down the line?

*I haven't turned the fridge on yet, though I suspect it will work fine for now. It also had some packaging damage (fridge not affected). I'm trying to figure out if I need to return it ASAP and how to best approach it. Any advice very welcome.*

[image: refrigerator wires and lines][image: wire1][image: wire2][image: wire3]

Comment: Was it built in Germany?  Are you also in Germany or are you somewhere where it had to be transported via ocean freight?

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate It could have been transported by sea or land. It's made in Germany, I bought it in Lithuania.

Comment: Hmmm... either by land or sea, Lithuania is a relatively short trip from Germany (for cargo). Thus, my initial thought is unlikely. That's some horribly ugly craftsmanship. Without removing all the crud (most likely flux), it's hard for me to tell if the underlying connections are affected. I have much welding experience, so me personally, I would clean it all up and inspect the connections. But that's a bit much to ask of someone without the requisite skills and experience. Hopefully someone will chime in with their thoughts. I feel your pain on what you see... that's not ideal.

Comment: If I take a guess, and this is just a guess without cleaning it all up and performing a thorough inspection, the connections are probably okay.  But my 3 biggest concerns are: (1) what is the quality of those connections given the questionable craftsmanship, (2) have the underlying pipes/hoses been compromised by the chemical reactions you can visibly see on the surface, (3) was this appliance (or parts of it) exposed to abnormal conditions that caused these chemical reactions?

Comment: Bottom line: I think whatever brazing flux they used was possibly contaminated causing one heck of a mess.  Whether or not the result is only cosmetic, I really can't tell without cleaning it all up to see the condition of the underlying connections and pipes.

Comment: That's not normal.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, much appreciated! 
Small update: The seller claims it's normal (without even taking a look at photos!) and in fact I would find the same if I replaced the fridge/bought it somewhere else. (I'll try to validate it somehow.)

Comment: So this is what they do with melted AC coils contaminated with iron. "The seller claims it's normal" can I have the name so i can put it on the NO list? *Liebherr* ? Maybe they should stick to making cranes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a normal condition for an old refrigerator let alone a brand new one. I've swapped out many refrigerators over the years and have never seen anything like this on new ones. I would seriously think about returning it. It looks like a very poor repair job to me, not a factory install job.

Comment: Looks like a factory refurb job on an old fridge that had new outside panels slapped on an old chassis. I would _definitely_ return it!